# How to check with fluent validation of a property, if the data type is long

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am new to using Fluent validation and wanted to add some custom validation, since I did not find out of the box to validate the data type of Longs. I am created a method to parse and check for Long in my API response.. but I was bot able to add it using fluent validation. I am getting an error cannot convert from method group to Func <long,bool>

```
   public static class CustomSchemaValidators
    {
        public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, long> LongValidation<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, long> ruleBuilder)
        {
            return ruleBuilder.Must(IsLong).WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' is not a Long Data Type");
        }

        private static bool IsLong(string input)
        {
            Int64 r;
            return Int64.TryParse(input, out r);        
        }
    }
```

Comment: `value.GetType() == typeof(long)` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is close, but needs to accept a string value rather than long. Inlining the parse, it could look like this:

```
public static class CustomSchemaValidators
{
    public static IRuleBuilderOptions<T, string> LongValidation<T>(this IRuleBuilder<T, string> ruleBuilder)
    {
        return ruleBuilder.Must(x => long.TryParse(x, out _)).WithMessage("'{PropertyName}' is not a Long Data Type");
    }
}
```

Comment: but with this I am expecting a string.. I can not apply this to check the data type of property like so..    I have keep converting to a ToString().. and here ID is not a Long data type but it passes because I am converting it                                                                                                    
   public class SchemaValidator : AbstractValidator<ClassName>
            {
                public SchemaValidator ()
                {
                    RuleFor(property => property.item.Id.ToString()).LongValidation();
                }

            }